# Using dozer for copying java objects

Tags: java, object, copy, dozer

I am new to dozer framework. I want to copy some objects to a Map using dozer.

For instance Belwo is the example scenario which reflects my requirement.

```
  public void createUser(String userId,String password,String firstname)
  {
      Map<String,String> userMap=new HashMap<String,String>();

      userMap.put("LoginId",userId);
      userMap.put("password",password);
      userMap.put("FirstName",firstName);

      createUSerInApp(userMap);
   }.
```

I want to automatically copy the required properties like userId,password,firstname into userMap using dozer.

Can any one give any suggestions.

Thanks,
Narendra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT 1

> I was wrong!!!
>
> Check [this out](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/mapbackedproperty.html).  You can specify
>   the key in your map for the property,
>   should work like a charm. :)

I could be wrong, but I know of no built in functionality to perform the mapping you describe, so I think it will take a  [Custom Converter](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/customconverter.html).  Dozer really has great documentation.

I do highly recomend dozer.  It may seem like more work setting it up, and learning it, but you have a hold of it (it won't take long to learn) it's really flexible and easy to maintain.

Comment: In given link examples illustarating mapping class atrributes to another class attributes. But I require to map parameters of my method to a map.

Comment: Ok I did misread your question.  I thought you were going from Object -> Map or Map -> Object.  Dozer won't read all of your parameters and put them into a Map, but if your paremeters were in a like a request object, it could map the request objects attributes to the be in the map like the way the link I attached does.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. I am also thinking the same.